# How to properly use end() when using multiple EIPs in Camel Java DSL

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have 3 questions:

1. Are there generic recommendations how patterns e.g: splitter, multicast, aggregator, recipientList or pollEnrich should be closed in Java DSL? Something like: always use .end() after the pattern was invoked?
   This is a "clean code" related question and is about good practices when using Camel Java DSL.
2. In Sample 1. why do we have to use end() two times to get splitter and aggregationStrategy working properly?
3. Is Sample 2. correct if it comes to using endChoice() and end() (i.e. used as designed; having in mind good practices and that pollEnrich is used inside splitter)?

**Sample 1.**

```
.from(uri1)
    .process(processor0)
    .split(inputFiles, aggregationStrategy)
        .process(processor1)
        .pollEnrich().simple(fileUri)
        .toD(uri2)
        .end()
    .end()
    .processor(processor2)
    .toD(uri3)
```

If we take into account only calls to processor1, aggregationStrategy and processor2, the sequence of calls will be:

- processor1
- aggregationStrategy
- processor1
- aggregationStrategy
- processor2

what is expected behaviour.

If for example one or both end() will be removed the sequence of calls is as follows:

- processor1
- processor2
- aggregationStrategy
- processor1
- processor2
- aggregationStrategy

Above sequence of calls was introduced in an **EDIT** for Souciance Eqdam Rashti.

**Sample 2.**

```
.from(uri1)
    .process(processor0)
    .split(inputFiles)
        .process(processor1)
        .choice()
            .when(predicate)
                .pollEnrich.simple(fileUri)
                .process(processor2)
                .process(processor3)
                .to(uri1)
            .endChoice()
        .end()
    .end()
    .processor(processor4)
```

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: It would be easier if we saw the entire route code to know which start belongs to which end.

Comment: I've added the rest of the pseudocode to the routes.

Comment: Something is not right because you don't really need any end() for the Sample 1. For Sample 2 you need one .end() to close the .choice(). Which Camel version do you use?

Comment: I am using Camel 2.17.0 ; I thought that samples will be self-explaining, by the end of the day I will provide more details.

Comment: You should not need any end for Sample1. That's how I normally use it.

Comment: I've added some additional details to the questions, hope this will help in answering.